# How do I access Crystal Reports on MS SQL 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have some code I am trying to update that was not written by me and it looks like it is using Crystal Reports with MSSQL 2005?

```
SSRSreport oReport = new SSRSreport( screenInfo.ProcInfo[0].ProcParms.Count, "/dir/" + reportFilename,
                                    AppSettings.GetAppSettings()["RptServerURL"].ToString() );

...
                Byte[] vOutput = oReport.RenderReport();
```

I notice it has a connection to some server too:

```
<add key="RptServerURL" value="http://doain.com/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx"/>
    <add key="RptServerDomain" value=""/>
    <add key="RptServerUsername" value=""/>
    <add key="RptServerPassword" value=""/>
    <add key="DisplayErrors" value="false"/>
    <add key="Beta" value="false"/>
```

So my question is. How do I access this template, I guess you could say, so I could edit the data that is being generated to a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to generate a SQl server reporting services report. [SSRS info from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx)

There is usually a report definition stored on the Report Server that is like a template that you feed your data in.

In your situation it looks like there is a web service deployed that receives the data, processes it and feeds it into the SSRS. I would inspect what the web service does by accessing its definition(WSDL) by following the url to your web service and adding ?wsdl at the end.(sorry not enough points to post all the links)

Once you know what the web service does, you can check and see if the is a RDL file generated for you report.

Here is some info on RDL: [Report Definition Language (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155062.aspx)

Hope this gets you started.

Cheers